# Pandas DataFrame GroupBy and New Calculated Columns Based on subsets of grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, websocket

I am a starter with pandas, picked it up as it seemed to be most popular and easiest to work with based on reviews. My intention is fast data processing using async processes (pandas don't really support async, but haven't reached that problem yet). If you believe I could use better library for my needs based on below scenarios, please let me know.

My code is running websockets using asyncio which are fetching activity data constantly and storing it into a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
data_set.loc[len(data_set)] = [datetime.now(),res['data']['E'] ,res['data']['s'] ,res['data']['p'] ,res['data']['q'] ,res['data']['m']]
```

That seems to work while printing out the results. The data frame gets big quickly, so have clean up function checking len() of data frame and drop() rows.

My intention is to take the full set in data_set and create a summary view based on a group value and calculate additional values as analytics using the grouped data and data points at different date_time snaps. These calculations would be running multiple times per second.
What I mean is this (all is made up, not a working code example just principle of what's needed):

```
grouped_data = data_set.groupby('name')
stats_data['name'] = grouped_data['name'].drop_duplicates()
stats_data['latest'] = grouped_data['column_name'].tail(1)
stats_data['change_over_1_day'] = ? (need to get oldest record that's within 1 day frame (out of multiple day data), and get value from specific column and compare it against ['latest']
stats_data['change_over_2_day'] = ?
stats_data['change_over_3_day'] = ?
stats_data['total_over_1_day'] = grouped_data.filter(data > 1 day ago).sum(column_name)
```

I have googled a million things, every time the examples are quite basic and don't really help my scenarios.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should use  Dask for async processes - https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/asynchronous.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was a bit vague I guess, but after some more research (googling) and trial/error (hours) managed to accomplish all that I mentioned here.
Hopefully can help someone to save some time who are new to this:

```
stats_data = data.loc[trade_data.groupby('name')['date_time'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
1_day_ago = data.loc[data[data.date_time > day_1].groupby("name")["date_time"].idxmin()].drop(labels = ['date_time','id','volume','flag'], axis=1).set_index('name')['value']
stats_data['change_over_1_day'] = stats_data['value'].astype('float') / stats_data['name'].map(1_day_ago).astype('float') * 100 - 100
```

Same principal applied to other columns.
If anyone has a much more efficient/faster way to do this, please post your answer.